# Sending udp packets between computers in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am trying to send an udp packet from one computer to another in a local network. One computer is running Windows 10, other Ubuntu 18.04.

The code I have so far is this:

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
namespace udpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            string ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
            IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, 20020);
            var udp = new UdpClient(ipadd.ToString(), 20020);
            while (true) {
                var recvData = udp.ReceiveAsync().Result;
                System.Console.WriteLine($"received: {recvData.Buffer}");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
namespace C_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var udp = new UdpClient();
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(420);
            var i = udp.SendAsync(bytes, bytes.Length, "fe80::7077:8d67:4984:c9bc%43", 20020 ).Result;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"sent: {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

(I changed the ipv6 address a bit but format is exactly the same).
I get no errors when sending or anything, it just goes through but the server does not catch it. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. So any pointers would be most appreciated.

Edit: updated code works within lan, but not outside LAN.
Client:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var udp = new UdpClient("192.168.1.117", 20020);
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(420);
            var i = udp.SendAsync(bytes, bytes.Length).Result;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"sent: {i}");
        }
```

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 20020);
            var udp = new UdpClient(serverEndPoint);
            while (true) {
                var recvData = udp.ReceiveAsync().Result;
                System.Console.WriteLine($"received: {recvData.Buffer}");
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Did you try `IPAddress.Any` for listening?

Answer (score 1):

first try IPAddress.Any since using the first IP address from `Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();` is not guaranteed to be the IPv6 address you are using, specially if the computer has more than one network adapter.

Second is using the serverEndPoint you created for the `UdpClient` constructor

```
// Use IPAddress.Any
IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Any;
var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipadd, 20020);
// Use the serverEndPoint for the UP
var udp = new UdpClient(serverEndPoint);
```

Third, check the server's firewall settings and make sure you allow incoming UDP messages on port 20020 (by default on both Windows and Ubuntu it is not allowed). And check the client firewall settings and make sure outgoing UDP messages on port 20020 are allowed (by default on both Windows and Ubuntu it is allowed).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried doing what you  mentioned (set server endpoint to IPAddress.Any, checked if connections are blocked etc.) I could get a connection with the local router IP (192.168.1.117). However if I want to connect between routers it still cannot do it. As always I get no errors, I updated the code I have now in the OP.